# Loader that doesn't render children unless data is fetched

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to make a component that renders "children" prop only "and only if" a boolean is true, now i noticed if i do something like this

```js
const QueryLoader = (props) => {
  if (!props.isSuccess) return <h2>Loading</h2>;
  return props.children;
};
```

and use it as follows

```js
const Main = (props) => {
const {isSuccess,data} = fetcher("api");
  return (
    <QueryLoader isSuccess={isSuccess}>
      <div>{data.arrayOfData.innerSomething}</div>
    </QueryLoader>
  );
};
```

the **data.arrayOfData.innerSomething** is still triggered which is causing me issues, i thought about instead of sending children i send a component as a function and then call it inside the QueryLoader but i dont know if this has any side-effects.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [render prop pattern](https://reactpatterns.com/#render-prop):

```
const QueryLoader = ({ isSuccess, children }) => {
  return isSuccess ? children() : <h2>Loading</h2>;
};

const Main = () => {
  const { isSuccess, data } = fetcher("api");
  return (
    <QueryLoader isSuccess={isSuccess}>
      {() => <div>{data.arrayOfData.innerSomething}</div>}
    </QueryLoader>
  );
};
```

For data fetching I hightly recommend using [react-query](https://tanstack.com/query) library.

Comment: True this is the only way i got it working, but i dont know if it has any issues, i am using react-query but didn't mention it, and preferred a generic solution, the issue with this solution is that it makes the JSX looks scrambled a bit with functions inside it

Comment: @Menawer If you developing a generic loader with, for example, a loading indicator and an errors handling or something thats a different question.